# implementing ios deeplinks ionic 3

Tags: ios, ionic3

I’ve been working on deeplinks for my ionic 3 app and successfully it worked on android devices, however by the ionic-plugin-deeplinks i have to setup the file apple-app-site-association and upload it to “my hosting https service to .well-known folder”, the problem here is i dont have any hosting, im just publishing the app to the google/apple store directly, i’m not hosting anything, neither services.

so, how can i setup in this case deeplinks on ios??, i only need to make it works publishing my app in the apple store…

thanks in advance.

Comment: Deeplinks are there so that a user who is trying to access a page of your website, can continue their experience on an equivilent page within the associated app. What do you want to acheive with deeplinks if you don't have a website ?

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeah after a research apple docs clarify i need a website in order to set universal links, so im planning to code a website then, thanks.